# Web Forms Application fails to load Exceptionless.Portable - incorrect version

Tags: c#, asp.net, exceptionless

I am adding Exceptionless to my WebForms application via nuget.  The application compiles but I get a runtime error when visiting a page:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Exceptionless.Portable, Version=3.1.1416.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fc181f0a46f65747' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The issue is `3.1.1416.0`.  It shouldn't be trying to load this version as I am currently using version `3.2.1424.0`.  I've checked web.config and no runtime reassignment exists.

My web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="exceptionless" type="Exceptionless.ExceptionlessSection, Exceptionless.Extras" />
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    </configSections>
    ....
    <exceptionless apiKey="***********" enabled="true" />
    ....
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <add name="ExceptionlessModule" type="Exceptionless.Web.ExceptionlessModule, Exceptionless.Web" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Where is my application picking up  `3.1.1416.0` from?

1. Checked `web.config` (see above)
2. Checked versions of all Exceptionless References Assemblies: `Exceptionless.Extras`, `Exceptionless.Portable`, `Exceptionless.Web`.  All are at version `3.2.1424.0`.
3. Checked IISExpress configuration files `applicationhost.config`, `redirection.config`, `aspnet.config`
4. Done a "Search in Files" (*.*) for version number - nothing!

Assembly Load Trace is as follows (which as you can see refers *only* to the incorrect assembly version:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Exceptionless.Portable, Version=3.1.1416.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fc181f0a46f65747
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/TFS/DALS/Main/Source/Core/StaffPages/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\TFS\DALS\Main\Source\Core\StaffPages\bin
Calling assembly : DerbyLib, Version=2.2.5855.29039, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cfdbfaae31cae294.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TFS\DALS\Main\Source\Core\StaffPages\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Chris\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Exceptionless.Portable, Version=3.1.1416.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fc181f0a46f65747
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Chris/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/ec9388cd/d1727d5c/Exceptionless.Portable.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Chris/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/ec9388cd/d1727d5c/Exceptionless.Portable/Exceptionless.Portable.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TFS/DALS/Main/Source/Core/StaffPages/bin/Exceptionless.Portable.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your first time with it or were you using `3.1.1416.0` at one point and have upgraded to `3.2.1424.0`? If so, you may need to clean or manually wipe your `bin` folder. If not, try setting up a new solution, install Exceptionless, do a minimum viable test to make sure it's working, and use those assemblies in your existing project.

Comment: I presume I was using `3.1.1416.0` in the recent past.  Yes I did try clearing `bin` and `obj` folders, did a clean solution and cleared out `Temp` folders but these didn't work.  I've not tried creating a new solution because it will take days to migrate all code into new Projects etc. as well as the hell it will bring to Source Control. Sorry but thanks.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh You misunderstand. I'm not advising you to move all your code to a new project. I'm advising you to set up a test bed to get the 1424 version working and then to move working test bed assemblies to your main project.

Comment: Thanks @Bigsby.  So, I can set up a test project/solution for Exceptionless `3.2.1424.0` and test that they work correctly.  After that however, in order to "move working test bed assemblies to your main project" - are you suggesting doing away with pulling Exceptionless from NuGet?  Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisWalsh As an immediate next step, yes. If that works, try going back to NuGet.

Comment: Will do.  I'll let you know how I get on. Cheers

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I know I'm a bit late... I work on the Exceptionless project and would be more than happy to help out as well.